# function like map() that doesn't create a new array

Tags: javascript

Is there a function like map() in JS that stores the returns in the original array, instead of making a new array? If not, what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can use `forEach`.

Comment: [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)

Comment: You can assign the value that return map function to the variable of the list you're iterating over map.

Comment: caution: there's a *reason* map returns a new array...

Comment: The idea behind map is that you can modify the data contained within an array without modifying the original data.

Comment: @RichardChristensen the OP appears to know this, and why bother creating a new array if you don't need one ?

Comment: what I am trying to do is replace something like this:
`color[0]+=Math.random()*noise-noise/2;`
`color[1]+=Math.random()*noise-noise/2;`
`color[2]+=Math.random()*noise-noise/2;`

Comment: This is how you do it `var arr = [1,2,3,4]; arr = arr.map(e => e*2); console.log(arr);`

Comment: @Redu no, it isn't - that has created a _new_ array, which leaves any other element holding a reference to that array now holding a reference to a different array.

Comment: @BobPickle p.s. you can in theory make your noise function more efficient with `color[n] += noise * (Math.random() - 0.5)` - replacing a potentially expensive division operation with a subtraction.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes right then let's do some side effect job...  `var arr = [1,2,3,4], brr = arr; arr.map((e,i,a) => a[i] = e*2); console.log(brr);`

Comment: @Redu that fixes the side effect problem, but still creates (and then throws away) a new array, unnecessarily.  Please _read_ my answer.

Comment: @BobPickle To avoid arguments could you edit your question to include WHY you want to do this? What is your main goal?

Comment: @RichardChristensen IMNSHO the question is perfectly clear.  There's any number of reasons why you'd want to mutate an array in-place instead of making a mutated copy.

Answer (score 6):

Just use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead:

```
myArray.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
    array[index] = ...   // some mutation of value
});
```

The exact same code would still work with `.map` (which invokes the callback with the same three parameters and therefore allows in-place mutation) but `.forEach` avoids the overhead of creating a new array, only to have it thrown away again immediately.

Note also that whilst one *could* just refer to `myArray` inside the callback, it's much more efficient not to.  Having the `array` parameter passed to the callback allows the callback to manipulate or access the original array without requiring it to be in the lexical scope (although using this to insert or delete elements would be ill advised)

Comment: Great answer! I just want to add that the reason it's more efficient to use the array variable from the arguments is because many JavaScript engines optimize functions that don't reference lexical scopes by omitting variable lookups in the function definition's lexical scopes. You can even confirm this in a browser debugger by setting a breakpoint inside this function and trying to access a lexical variable. It'll error.

Comment: Good answer. The only addendum I would make is that this approach allows one to not only alter the value on individual elements of the array, but also to add or remove elements from the array while iterating over it. One should do this with caution, because the behavior may or may not be what you expect (and may vary between implementations).

Comment: @SMcCrohan I think the spec guarantees that the array indices are determined just once before iteration starts, but I would never recommend actually changing the array size during such a loop.

Comment: Right. I definitely wasn't intending to ENDORSE the practice...more like 'call out the possibility so as to have an opportunity to warn against it' :)